# AWS Beanstalk "eb-docker" is not registered

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecr

I have a Docker-backed AWS Elastic Beanstalk application. I pull the image from a private AWS ECR.
However, I get the "Instance deployment failed..." error. In the logs, I see

> 2021/12/08 21:57:49.261047 [INFO] Executing instruction: RestartAppServer
> 2021/12/08 21:57:49.261050 [INFO] Restarting customer application...
> 2021/12/08 21:57:49.261065 [INFO] detected current app is not docker compose app
> 2021/12/08 21:57:49.261073 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker.service
> 2021/12/08 21:57:49.265842 [WARN] stopProcess Warning: process eb-docker is not registered  > 2021/12/08 21:57:49.265859 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop eb-docker.service
> 2021/12/08 21:57:49.270477 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf eb-docker.service
> 2021/12/08 21:57:49.275369 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [restart-app-server] - [RestartAppServer]. Stop running the command. Error: startProcess Failure: process "eb-docker" is not registered

What do I do about this? How to register "eb-docker"?
My Dockerrun.aws.json is quite simple

```
    {
        "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
        "Image": {
            "Name": "**.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/*:*",
            "Update": "true"
        },
        "Ports": [
            {
                "ContainerPort": "80"
          }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Which AMI are you using?

Comment: It is Amazon Linux 2

Comment: Can you ensure you are using an AMI that is compatible with ECS/Elastic beanstalk? Refer to this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html

Comment: Should be ok with that, it is based on ASP.NET Core Runtime latest image 6.0, which uses Debian 11. The image is built on GithubActions, so the Docker version should be fine as well. The image works fine on Azure, or when run locally.

Comment: @gajo357, were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I abandoned AWS and implemented everything in Azure.